# How to Change the look of Openbox?

Tags: openbox

I am using Openbox Environment in Ubuntu 11.10, i wanted to know if there is any way to  make it Decently-Aesthetic.

- Change Wallpaper
- Change Iconset
- Add Menubar
- Thats it

Comment: I have reedited with my needs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Debian's OpenBox Page](http://wiki.debian.org/Openbox) has a lot of what you're after in terms of customisation. Actually, it covers everything you're asking about (icons are part of the theme).

[Ubuntu's own OpenBox page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox) isn't bad either! It has a similar amount of information (it does look suspiciously similar!) but there are some Ubuntu-only notes in there too. Some of the information does look a little old (~2006 era), so be careful when basing your changes on the information there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gnome/Openbox, you can change the wallpaper under `System Settings > Appearance` --  I'm running Gnome-do, so I launch system settings that way, though from the terminal you can also launch "gnome-panel" which should give you an `Applications` menu with `System Tools` > `System Settings` available.

There's also a nice `Advanced Settings` dialog that I launch with Gnome-do where you can set other options, including iconsets.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using feh to change your desktop. Or you can add "gnome-settings-daemon &" to your autostart.sh and change your global desktop from "appearance settings".  You can change the cursor with "sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme" and gnome-tweak-tool after enabling the Daemon. As for the menu bar, I like to use "gnome-panel"....

Note that both gnome-tweak-tool and gnome-panel require installing the Gnome DE packages.